# Is ReportViewer 2012 compatible with SSRS Server 2005 for remote access?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, compatibility, reportviewer

While attempting to view a report in ReportViewer 2012 from SSRS 2005 in remote mode I am getting error: "*Remote report processing requires Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services or later.*"

Are they compatible or not? Or is it just a matter of changing endpoint WebService URL from `http://machine/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx` to something else? It seems to work fine connecting to SSRS 2008 though.

If they're incompatible, could someone please provide a full compatibility list - which ReportViewer can be run with which SSRS service:

ReportViewer v11 (2012) is compatible with SSRS (2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012) ?

ReportViewer v10 (2010) is compatible with SSRS (2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012) ?

ReportViewer v9 (2008) is compatible with SSRS (2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReportViewer v9: SSRS 2005 (kind of 2008+) 
--A few rendering anomalies and features that do not work properly.

ReportViewer v10,v11: SSRS 2008 - SSRS 2012
-- Will not support SQL Server Reporting Services 2005